# Best tool or approach to cross reference elements on a illustration

Tags: inkscape, illustration

I'm working on a programming assignment, where I'd like to document related data structures - JSON to be precise.

I use Inkscape and it's diagram connector tool. The result I am getting looks as follows:

[image]

The arrows are attached to boxes, which are manually put on top of the text.

Is there a way, to:

1. have the arrows stick to text itself,
2. allow the text to be editable,
3. draw a box around the selected text?

The end goal is to having a maintainable version of the drawing.
As for now, that is the first creation of the illustration, it is Ok to have it done the way it is, but when the text changes (to reflect the development progress) I'd like to do as little manual adjustments as possible.

Any other tips regarding technical documentation of the kind are welcome as well.

Comment: Your'e using Inkscape, but did not tag this question with the Inkscape tag. Does that mean you are open to *any* application or are you looking for an Inkscape solution?

Comment: Howabout generating the pictures with code? its not tertibly hard to search the injected texts and add the arrows in. This has the benefit of auto generating the image in a programmer friendly fashion, just add a text editor.

Answer (score 1):

I've advocated for OpenOffice.org Draw / Writer as a tool for flow charts before and this is a perfect example. While if you're set on using Inkscape my answer doesn't help because my answer is to use OpenOffice.org Draw instead.

It has very good arrows and connectors that are easy to use. I've even saved .PDFs from there for the sole purpose of getting the arrows into Illustrator. Here's a simple screenshot showing the connector tab and how it might work for your application:

[image: OpenOffice.org Draw connectors]

Comment: Thank You for the suggestion. I'm evaluating it right now.